# Is it possible to view the machine code generated by the JVM hotspot compiler?

Tags: java, bytecode, machine-code

I was wondering, is it possible to get eyes on the actual machine code that the HotSpot compiler generates when it compiles a given Java bytecode class or method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Translate ByteCode to Machine Native Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167479/how-translate-bytecode-to-machine-native-code)

Comment: Even if it's ... it won't be readable.

Comment: I actually don't want to use it to improve performance, just to get eyes on the actual machine code for a computer architecture course.

Comment: Though there are [3rd-party tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167479/how-translate-bytecode-to-machine-native-code?rq=1) for such compilation, this is not what normally happening, unless your inquiry is about [JIT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/underst_jit.html) compilation.

Comment: My inquiry is just to get a look on the actual machine code to describe the different levels.

Comment: Creating it on your own can be a bit fiddly (as mentioned in the answer below, this requires the hsdis-file, and obtaining or even compiling this may not be worth the effort if you "just want to have a look at the results") - but you can find several StackOverflow answers where people posted the JIT-result-machine code for analyzing certain problems.

Comment: See also this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341083/how-to-use-xxunlockdiagnosticvmoptions-xxcompilecommand-print-option-with-j

Answer (score 11):

Yes, with `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly` the Hotspot VM can give you that information when it actually executes (compiles) a given bytecode method.

See for example [HotSpotInternals Wiki:Print Assembly](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PrintAssembly) for details. It does require a disassembler module (hsdis-*.dll on Windows).

A bit more comfortable is using [JITWatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch/wiki) (but it uses the same infrastructure from HotSpot).