# How to see the machine code generated for JNI-Calls?

Tags: assembly, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I want to see the machine code generated by the JVM to call a native method [See here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24747484/13912132).
I know the Option -XX:+PrintAssembly (Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24718356/13912132) , but it only shows me the JIT-compiled code. I only want to see the short snippet, that sets up the registers/the stack, nothing else. [The code to generate machine code for x86_64](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/cpu/x86/sharedRuntime_x86_64.cpp#L1922).
Is there any commandline option that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-XX:+PrintAssembly` shows that, too. But there are nuances.

Even though a native method does not have bytecodes, the activation of the method still requires JVM to do [some work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746776/what-does-a-jvm-have-to-do-when-calling-a-native-method/24747484#24747484). Like with normal Java methods, this activation can be either interpreted or JIT compiled.

A native method always has a special entry point for calling from interpreter. This entry is a part of the interpreter, and is shared between all regular native methods. Or, more precisely, there are two entry points: for synchronized methods and for non-synchronized, see [`TemplateInterpreterGenerator::generate_native_entry()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/efc74b005823/src/hotspot/cpu/x86/templateInterpreterGenerator_x86.cpp#l782).

To print these entry points, use `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintInterpreter`, then look for `method entry point (kind = native)` in the output:

```
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x0000017e83dbefc0, 0x0000017e83dbfa60]  2720 bytes

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Argument 0 is unknown.RIP: 0x17e83dbefc0 Code size: 0x00000aa0
  0x0000017e83dbefc0:   mov     rcx,qword ptr [rbx+8h]
  0x0000017e83dbefc4:   movzx   ecx,word ptr [rcx+34h]
  0x0000017e83dbefc8:   pop     rax
  0x0000017e83dbefc9:   lea     r14,[rsp+rcx*8+0fffffffffffffff8h]
  0x0000017e83dbefce:   push    0h
  0x0000017e83dbefd3:   push    0h
  0x0000017e83dbefd8:   push    rax
  0x0000017e83dbefd9:   push    rbp
  0x0000017e83dbefda:   mov     rbp,rsp
  0x0000017e83dbefdd:   push    r13
  0x0000017e83dbefdf:   push    0h
  0x0000017e83dbefe4:   mov     r13,qword ptr [rbx+8h]
  ...
```

If a native method is invoked many enough times, it gets JIT-compiled. I mean, the JVM generates a *wrapper* for calling the target native function from Java. Unlike the shared interpreter native entry, the wrapper is specialized for the particular native method.

When `-XX:+PrintCompilation` is on, you'll see native wrappers marked by `n` symbol:

```
    667   18     n 0       java.lang.Thread::isAlive (native)
```

You'll also find these wrappers in `-XX:+PrintAssembly` output:

```
java/lang/Thread.isAlive()Z  [0x00000238d2d62740, 0x00000238d2d62988]  584 bytes
Argument 0 is unknown.RIP: 0x238d2d62740 Code size: 0x00000248
[Entry Point]
  # {method} {0x00000238e5ebadd8} 'isAlive' '()Z' in 'java/lang/Thread'
  #           [sp+0x70]  (sp of caller)
  0x00000238d2d62740: mov     r10d,dword ptr [rdx+8h]
  0x00000238d2d62744: mov     r12,800000000h
  0x00000238d2d6274e: add     r10,r12
  0x00000238d2d62751: xor     r12,r12
  0x00000238d2d62754: cmp     rax,r10
  0x00000238d2d62757: je      238d2d62768h
  0x00000238d2d6275d: jmp     238cb2c7480h      ;   {runtime_call ic_miss_stub}
  0x00000238d2d62762: nop     word ptr [rax+rax+0h]
[Verified Entry Point]
  0x00000238d2d62768: mov     dword ptr [rsp+0ffffffffffff9000h],eax
  0x00000238d2d6276f: push    rbp
  0x00000238d2d62770: mov     rbp,rsp
  0x00000238d2d62773: sub     rsp,60h
  0x00000238d2d62777: mov     qword ptr [rsp+20h],rdx
  0x00000238d2d6277c: cmp     rdx,0h
  0x00000238d2d62780: lea     rdx,[rsp+20h]
  0x00000238d2d62785: cmove   rdx,qword ptr [rsp+20h]  ; ImmutableOopMap{[32]=Oop }
  0x00000238d2d6278b: vzeroupper
  ...
```

This code is generated by [`SharedRuntime::generate_native_wrapper`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/efc74b005823/src/hotspot/cpu/x86/sharedRuntime_x86_64.cpp#l1893).

Comment: Thank you for this great answer